# Internet Explorer 8 does not render the bundles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-8, bundle

I created a page that has bundles for CSS and JavaScript. Everything went well until testing for Internet Explorer 8. 
The tests are being run on a Windows XP virtual machine with Windows updates disabled. Thus, the version of IE8 is really neat. 
My problems only happen in this browser. All other tests running fine. 
Is there any hint? 
thank you

**EDIT**

When the browsers load the page, we can see the link to bundles generated by c# and the result file too. So, the IE doesnt render this css.

**EDIT IN TIME**

Right before a send this, a did another search and I guess i found the answer.
At the tops of generated bundle, is an error:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(12907,28): run-time error CSS1038: Expected hex color, found '#porcentagem-container'
(12929,25): run-time error CSS1038: Expected hex color, found '#porcentagem-container'
(13663,21): run-time error CSS1038: Expected hex color, found '#porcentagem-container'
(13663,43): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '     
(14222,15): run-time error CSS1038: Expected hex color, found '#porcentagem-container'
(14222,37): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '   
(25557,27): run-time error CSS1038: Expected hex color, found '#porcentagem-container'
```

I'll check all those errors and come back here with the answer (If i got some).

Thanks

Comment: Can you define "does not render"? Are they there at all? Are they just not minified?

Comment: It could have something to do with the file size limitations certain IE versions impose: http://joshua.perina.com/africa/gambia/fajara/post/internet-explorer-css-file-size-limit

Comment: @Calum you are right! Please, answer the question to mark as resolved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a file size limit of roughly 288kb for individual files in IE9 and below. Only content read before hitting this limit will be processed.

Please see:
http://joshua.perina.com/africa/gambia/fajara/post/internet-explorer-css-file-size-limit